# PySpark: Replace null values with empty list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, null

I outer joined the results of two `groupBy` and `collect_set` operations and ended up with this dataframe (`foo`):

```py
>>> foo.show(3)
+---+------+------+
| id|    c1|    c2|
+---+------+------+
|  0|  null|   [1]|
|  7|   [6]|  null|
|  6|   [6]|[7, 8]|
+---+------+------+
```

I want to concatenate `c1` and `c2` together to obtain this result:

```py
+---+------+------+---------+
| id|    c1|    c2|      res|
+---+------+------+---------+
|  0|  null|   [1]|      [1]|
|  7|   [6]|  null|      [6]|
|  6|   [6]|[7, 8]|[6, 7, 8]|
+---+------+------+---------+
```

To do this, I need to coalesce the null values in `c1` and `c2`. However, I don't even know what data type `c1` and `c2` are. How can I replace the null values with `[]` so that the concatenation of `c1` and `c2` will yield `res` as shown above?

This is how I'm currently concatenating both columns:

```py
# Concat returns null for rows where either column is null
foo.selectExpr(
    'id',
    'c1',
    'c2',
    'concat(c1, c2) as res'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with **`array_except,array_union`** functions for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([(0,[None],[1]),(7,[6],[None]),(6,[6],[7,8])],['id','c1','c2'])
df.withColumn("res",expr("""array_except(array_union(c1,c2),array(null))""")).show()
#+---+------+------+---------+
#| id|    c1|    c2|      res|
#+---+------+------+---------+
#|  0|[null]|   [1]|      [1]|
#|  7|   [6]|[null]|      [6]|
#|  6|   [6]|[7, 8]|[6, 7, 8]|
#+---+------+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `fillna`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Fill null values with empty list
foo = foo.fillna(F.lit([]), subset=['c1', 'c2'])

# now you can use your selectExpr
foo.selectExpr(
    'id',
    'c1',
    'c2',
    'concat(c1, c2) as res'
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, I'm getting an ugly error:
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList []